# getting error Error:res/menu/mainMenu.xml:invalid file name:must contain only[a-z0-9_.]

Tags: android

I am new to android and just started it. I created a file in res folder, menu/mainMenu.xml. But i got the error

```
Error: res/menu/mainMenu.xml: invalid file name: must contain only[a-z0-9_.]
```

When i changed the file name to just mainmenu(remove the capital M)  then it started working. Why? I am using intelliJ 10.5.1.

Thanks

Comment: XML files name should be always in lowercase latter only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it should be `mainmenu.xml` ,no capital letter is allowed in naming of xml files.

```
  File name must contain only lowercase a-z, 0-9, or _.
```

- only `a-z`,mind that not capital...and `white-space not allowed`
- name must start with a character.not with a Number(0-9)
- name only `_` symbol allowed.no other symbol alowed.

Comment: oh thanks for the answer and explanation of regex pattern also. :)

Answer (score 2):

xml file doesnot support capital letter in naming of xml file so try removing capital letter.

correct `mainmenu.xml` or `main_menu.xml`. For further detail you can look onto [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6808751/res-layout-contact-us-xml-invalid-file-name-must-contain-only-a-z0-9).