# Getting error on my eclipse

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse

```
res\raw\sounds-783-elastique.mp3: Invalid file name: must contain only [a-z]
```

This is the error i am getting on my eclipse.No Uppercase letters are involved as you can see. What do you think guys the problem is?

Comment: The character '-' in not allowed. only numbers, letters and underscore. Rename your file in sounds_783_elastique.mp3

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10913408/2345913

Comment: How can i vote you up or something like that

Answer (score 0):

Rename your mp3 file to `sounds_783_elastique.mp3`. Eclipse doesn't support '-' in file names.

Answer (score 0):

Your file name must be in the format:

```
(lowercase) -> a-z, 0-9,_
```