# How to load images from res/drawable-folder in ReactNative-App?

Tags: android, react-native

I'd like to display static images from res/drawable-folder in a ReactNative-App. However, there's nothing displayed.

I have the following folder structure in the android-subfolder:

```
macbook:CompanyApp hagen$ tree android/app/src/main/res/
android/app/src/main/res/
├── drawable
│   ├── a1456.jpg
│   └── a1457.jpg
├── mipmap-hdpi
│   └── ic_launcher.png
├── mipmap-mdpi
│   └── ic_launcher.png
├── mipmap-xhdpi
│   └── ic_launcher.png
├── mipmap-xxhdpi
│   └── ic_launcher.png
└── values
    ├── strings.xml
    └── styles.xml

6 directories, 8 files
```

As mentioned in the documentation, i try to load the image-files from drawable-folder with the following code:

```
<Image source={{uri: 'a1456'}} style={{width: 140, height: 140}} />
```

I also tried the filename together with the extension:

```
<Image source={{uri: 'a1456.jpg'}} style={{width: 140, height: 140}} />
```

and also:

```
<Image source={require('image!a1456')} style={{width: 140, height: 140, backgroundColor: 'yellow'}} />
```

And i tried the subfolder:

```
<Image source={{uri: 'drawable/a1456.jpg'}} style={{width: 140, height: 140}} />
```

No image will be displayed.
Using a require-statement within image source for a local image in my current folder for instance is working fine.

But i am looking for a solution to consume the drawable-images like within a real native android application.

**UPDATE**

I just published an example project on github: https://github.com/itinance/testdrawable

It is a standard RN-App with "react-native init" and just added an image to display in drawable-folder (android only).

Can someone have a look at it and tell me what i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Finally i got it: the `<Image>` Tag needs concrete "width" and "height" arguments as attributes, not only as style-parameter.

With that in mind, both declarations will work perfectly:

```
  <Image width={200} height={267} source={{uri: 'img_3665'}} style={{width: 200, height: 267}} />
  <Image width={200} height={267} source={require('image!img_3665')} style={{width: 200, height: 267}} />
```

Comment: This solution does not work for me. I have copied my image in drawable folder and trying to access using both methods but it does not work.
Using   
`<Image width={200} height={267} source={require('image!img_3665')} style={{width: 200, height: 267}} />`
I am getting 500 error from package manager saying module image!img_3665 not found

Comment: Also not working for me. When I set width/height it gives me warning and tells me to put it into style.

Comment: Do you know how to load image from the mdpi folder? Not from the drawable folder?

Comment: Doesn't work for me either. Which one worked? the uri or the require?

Comment: Magically source={{uri: 'splash_background'}} worked for me

Answer (score 2):

I am also trying to do this. Am using RN 0.47.1 - reason I want this, is because I want to have the "loading" screen and my landing page have an image in the exact same spot, so I want the image to load instantly.

Re instant loading: Adding the resource within the folder in my js bundled directories, is taking time to load it. So I thought that if I put it in "res/drawable" (for Android) it should already be loaded as it just used it for the splash. I have found this is true, however there is a blink, I am trying to avoid that blink.

However here is the official docs on how to load local images on Android and iOS - [facebook.github.io :: React Native - Images From Hybrid App's Resources](https://reactnative.dev/docs/images.html#images-from-hybrid-apps-resources)

> If you are building a hybrid app (some UIs in React Native, some UIs in platform code) you can still use images that are already bundled into the app.
>
> For images included via Xcode asset catalogs or in the Android drawable folder, use the image name without the extension:
>
> ```
> <Image source={{uri: 'app_icon'}} style={{width: 40, height: 40}} />
> ```
>
> For images in the Android assets folder, use the asset:/ scheme:
>
> ```
> <Image source={{uri: 'asset:/app_icon.png'}} style={{width: 40, height: 40}} />
> ```
>
> These approaches provide no safety checks. It's up to you to guarantee that those images are available in the application. Also you have to specify image dimensions manually.

So yes, your discovery of having to set the width/height is true. In latest RN though (i am using 0.47.1) we can't set props of width/height, it has to be done via `style`.

Comment: Hi Noitidart ! , Even I want to avoid the blink. Just curious to know How you avoided the white screen for a blink before splash screen?

Answer (score 0):

Sample project structure-
my app name is MyProject

```
Myproject
├── ios
├── android
├── resource  //folder for static content
    └── image.png
```

To use image residing in resource directory

```
<Image style={{width: 16, height: 16}} source={require('./resource/image.png') }  />
```

Hope it will help!

Comment: As written in my question, I already know how to load local images like you did :) The question was exactly, how to consume the images placed in drawable-folders with device-dependent dimensions like hdpi, ldpi and so on specifically on Android.

Comment: You can do so by using dimensions component to get width and height of device and pass image as needed

Answer (score 0):

Save images in drawable folder then you can add this code. This works for me.
`` <Image style={styles.imageStyle} source={ { uri: icon + `${Platform.OS === 'ios' ? '.jpg' : ''}` }} /> ``

Answer (score 0):

1. Add Image Component in import block.

   import {
     Platform,
     StyleSheet,
     Text,
     View,
     Image
   } from 'react-native';
2. Add Image tag in render’s return block.
   Source attribute in Image tag, where we are specifying the image location.
   Also we have added inline style to Image tag, that helps to set the image size as per the device width.
   For images in the Android assets folder, use the asset:/ scheme