# Bundling error adding image to React Native Android

Tags: react-native

I'm having an issue with adding static images to my project. I added a resource folder with images inside, restarted the packager and get the following error:

```
error: bundling failed: 
Error: Unable to resolve module `../../assets/img/receiptIcon.PNG` from
`C:\Users\Keith\Desktop\Phase1\Screens\Receipts\ReceiptRow.js`:
The module `../../assets/img/receiptIcon.PNG` could not be found from 
`C:\Users\Keith\Desktop\Phase1\Screens\Receipts\ReceiptRow.js`. Indeed, none of
these files exist:`C:\Users\Keith\Desktop\Phase1\assets\img\receiptIcon.PNG(.native||.android.js|.native.js|.js|.android.json|.native.json|.json)` 
 `C:\Users\Keith\Desktop\Phase1\assets\img\receiptIcon.PNG\index(.native||.android.js|.native.js|.js|.android.json|.native.json|.json)`
```

Copying the path below into File Explorer opens the image as expected. I've made sure there are no special chars in the file path as suggested in other posts, I've copied the image into the same directory as the js file but I still get an unresolved module error.

This is how I am adding the image: 
(I've tried using different paths with the same result, 'receiptIcon.png', './receiptIcon.png', './../../assets/img/receiptIcon.png', './../../assets/img/receiptIcon.PNG' )

```
    <View  style={styles.iconContainer}>
      {/* icon image*/}
      <Image source={require('./receiptIcon.PNG')} style={styles.icon} />
    </View>
```

Is there anything I am missing because as far as the documentation says I just need to add the image to the project dir and the packager does the rest?
I'm using 
react-native-cli: 2.0.1
react-native: 0.52.0

(I also have images working when loaded from a URL, from taking a picture and from the Camera Roll/Gallery)

Comment: add it in your android/app/src/main/assets/somefolder/image.png and use as <Image source={{uri : 'asset:/somefolder/image.png' }} />

Comment: No this didn't work, no errors just no image..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to load images from res/drawable-folder in ReactNative-App?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38174722/how-to-load-images-from-res-drawable-folder-in-reactnative-app)

Comment: @KeithBurke two things. 1. make sure you have a height and width. 2. make sure the path is proper. anything inside  'android/app/src/main/assets/' is mapped as 'asset:/' the remaining path has to be same

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what the issue was but after recreating my images (initially I used the windows snipping tool but used gimp this time) they all seem to work now from a resource folder in the root dir of my project, thank you for your help!