# how to get navigation parameters in a menu page using react native

Tags: react-native-navigation

How To read the parameters sent from a login page in menu page where navigation is defined using Drawer Navigator like below.

```
export default MyDrawerNavigator = DrawerNavigator({
    MainStack: {
        screen: FirstActivity_StackNavigator
    },
    SecondStack: {
        screen: SecondActivity_StackNavigator
    },
    ThirdStack: {
        screen: ThirdActivity_StackNavigator
    }
});
```

Comment: Could you please check the formatting of your post? I think the part starting with "export" should be formatted as code, but isn't.

Answer (score 0):

This line can return a parameters passed to your navigation :

```
this.props.navigation.getParam('PARAM_NAME', {
      PARAM_DEFAULT: 'DEFAULT_VALUE'
    });
```

PARAM_DEFAULT is return if no one paramater called 'PARAM_NAME' is defined
Hope it's the answer you're waiting for.

Comment: how to load images from a resources folders like drawable/mipmap  in react native app

Comment: For images try const logo = require('PATH_TO_IMAGE'); for drawable look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/38189437/10279256